# Will my Javascript BLE application that I wrote for Chrome on desktop also work on Chrome on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, bluetooth-lowenergy, desktop

I hacked together a website (HTML+CSS+Javascript only) that I use offline to control some Bluetooth Low energy devices. I was thinking of hosting it with Apache on my local network so that I could use it on laptops and maybe phones around the house. **I only use Chrome on all my devices.**

What would happen if I went to the website on my Android Phone? I assume the CSS and HTML would load fine but what happens to the Javascript? Will it run at all? Are all the BLE methods different?

PS: Basically I want to know if my idea is too far-fetched to even attempt. If it's way easier to just develop a separate app in Kotlin in Android Studio I'll take that route and not even bother with Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Web Bluetooth API was shipped on for desktop and Android since Chrome 56.

Check here: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5264933985976320